# Matching two arrays with identical strings but one with longer substrings

Tags: ruby, string

This problem came about because I was being stubborn and ended up getting some odd results in a coding challenge.  I was curious if it's possible to format these two arrays to look identical.

```
arr_1 = ["qrygn", "zrrg ng pubpbyngr pbeare", "gra zra", "gjb onpxhc grnzf", "zvqavtug rkgenpgvba"]

arr_2 = ["qrygn", "zrrg", "ng", "pubpbyngr", "pbeare", "gra", "zra", "gjb", "onpxhc", "grnzf", "zvqavtug", "rkgenpgvba"]
```

Knowing what you know about these two arrays, is there anyway to make `arr_2` look like `arr_1`?

Comment: Why not `output = arr_1.dup`?

Comment: We need to see evidence of your effort. "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)"
is your friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that:

1. you have `arr_1` for reference, and
2. you know that the tokens all appear in the same order, you could do something like:

```rb
lengths = arr_1.map {|v| v.split(" ").length }
tmp_arr_2 = arr_2.dup
lengths.map {|l| tmp_arr_2.shift(l) }.map {|v| v.join(" ") }
```

We get the number of words in each string in `arr_1`, then shift that many tokens off of `arr_2`, and join them with spaces.

Comment: This is perfect.  Don't quite understand it yet but I'll make sure I dive into it.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`doit?` returns `true` if some adjacent elements of `arr2` can be joined with a space between to create an array that equals `arr1`, else it returns `false`.

I assume that each element of `arr1` does not begin or end with a space and does not contain two consecutive spaces. (If those conditions are not met `doit?` can be modified, but it's messy.)

This solution is a head-slapper if you view the problem in the right way.

```
def doit?(arr1, arr2)
  arr1.flat_map { |s| s.split } == arr2
end
```

```
arr_1 = ["qrygn", "zrrg ng pubpbyngr pbeare", "gra zra",
         "gjb onpxhc grnzf", "zvqavtug rkgenpgvba"]

arr_2 = ["qrygn", "zrrg", "ng", "pubpbyngr", "pbeare", "gra", "zra",
         "gjb", "onpxhc", "grnzf", "zvqavtug", "rkgenpgvba"]

arr_3 = ["qrygn", "zrrg", "ng", "pubpybngr", "pbeare", "gra", "zra",
         "gjb", "onpxhc", "grnzf", "zvqavtug", "rkgenpgvba"]

arr_4 = ["qrygn"]
```

```
doit?(arr_1, arr_2)
  #=> true
doit?(arr_1, arr_3)
  #=> false
doit?(arr_1, arr_4)
  #=> false
```

Note:

```
arr_1.flat_map { |s| s.split }
  #=> ["qrygn", "zrrg", "ng", "pubpbyngr", "pbeare", "gra",
  #    "zra", "gjb", "onpxhc", "grnzf", "zvqavtug", "rkgenpgvba"]
```

Comment: You're not lying!  You made that all too simple!  Thanks a ton for the comment.